# Working with menus

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

In .NET/C++, I have a Form with a menu strip with many menus and submenus. 
.NET created code for me with the usual:

```
fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

Using `sender` and `e`, how do I know which menu and submenu was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You've shown very little code, so it's hard to give a definite answer.

If you have one click handler for all your menu items, the `sender` will be the object of the individual menu item that was clicked. Make sure all your menus & submenus have names (or, make sure the objects for each menu & submenu are stored somewhere), and compare to that.

You could also define one click handler for each menu item. In this case, you know who the sender is, because `fileToolStrip_File_New_Click()` is only called when File -> New is clicked.